# behat installation fails: unexpected T_SL

Tags: php, behat

```
root@hotspot1:/var/www/httpdocs/test1.<domain>.it# curl http://getcomposer.org/installer | php   
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100 67830    0 67830    0     0  32069      0 --

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in /var/www/httpdocs/test1.<domain>.it/- on line 818
```

I cannot understand to what's referring.

I know  T_SL is

```
<<
```

But, really, i've never used this token. I've this token i a third-party library, regardin Excel read/write, but it's not in the root.

I'm using php 5.2.* ob a old ubuntu 8

I read composer installer, looking for row 808. it's here the problem.

```
public static function getPackagedCaFile()
{
    $cacert = <<<'CACERT'
```

But, why is it a problem?

Comment: could you please output the code block of the variable $cacert?

Comment: seems problem with heredoc. Please check, http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know *precisely* what has caused this problem, but it's plain what the basic problem is. Behat and Composer both use namespaces and other >5.3 functionality. PHP 5.2 does not recognise this syntax and cannot properly parse the file, causing the kind of error that you see above.

As [the first sentence of the Behat docs](http://docs.behat.org/) says:

> Behat is an open source behavior-driven development framework for PHP 5.3 and 5.4.

Or as [the Composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) say:

> Composer requires PHP 5.3.2+ to run.

To uses Behat or Composer, you will need to use a modern version of PHP.

Comment: OMG... I loose composer, behat, codeception... only because my chef don't want to upgrade the server .. omg ...

Comment: @realtebo That's absurd. PHP 5.2 is 8 years old now (5.3 is only 5 years old...) and is no longer supported. The [backward incompatible changes](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) are fairly minor; all your old code would almost certainly work :-(

Comment: Of course, my code will work... my dev machine it's a 5.5 (it's a long, and sad, history), but on this server there are a lot of executables that will not run on upgraded machine, and my chef don't want a new server aside the existent one... amen.. i'll run test locally